# Java program(even no in even index and odd no in odd index)

Tags: java, arrays

So the question is to arrange an array where even number of an array is in even index and odd number of an array is in odd index.

Example 1:
[3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 6, 9, 9, 89, 10, 1]

Output:
[6, 3, 2, 9, 0, 9, 0, 89, 6, 1, 10]

Example 2:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2]

Output:
[2, 1, null, 1, null, 1, null, 1]

Example 3:
[2, 2, 2]

Output:
[2, null, 2, null, 2]

Example 4:
[1, 1, 1]

Output:
[null, 1, null, 1, null, 1]

(if the no of even or odd numbers are less, null value is put)

I have tried this program but I am unable to pass all test cases. Can anyone can come with the correct answer in java language. Here is the code which i tried:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class eveodd
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the no of elements");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        int p=0;
        int a[]=new int[n]; 
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
        }

        if(n%2==0)
        {
            p=n;
        }
        else
        {
            p=n+1;
        }
        Integer b[]=new Integer[100];

        int c=0;int d=1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                if(a[i]%2==0)
                {
                    b[c]=a[i];
                    c+=2;
                }
                if(a[i]%2!=0)
                {
                    b[d]=a[i];
                    d+=2;
                }


        }
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What i am doing is filling an array with null values with even number in even index and odd number in odd index of the array. The problem i am facing is till how much index should i print the final(b[]) array. Also, is there any other way to find the size of the final (b[]) array as i have given it the size of 100.
Any other solution or a different code (in java language) is welcome.

Comment: Create two arrays (or better List<Integer>) to hold even numbers and odd numbers separately. Put the numbers in these arrays while you read them from input. Then just zip these two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by counting the number of odd and even values, then calculate the size of the array needed for the result.

```
static Integer[] evenOdd(int... input) {
    int countEven = 0, countOdd = 0;
    for (int value : input) {
        if ((value & 1) == 0)
            countEven++;
        else
            countOdd++;
    }
    Integer[] result = new Integer[Math.max(countEven * 2 - 1, countOdd * 2)];

    int idxEven = -2, idxOdd = -1;
    for (int value : input)
        result[(value & 1) == 0 ? (idxEven += 2) : (idxOdd += 2)] = value;
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
    test(1);
    test(2);
    test(3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 6, 9, 9, 89, 10, 1);
    test(1, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    test(2, 2, 2);
    test(1, 1, 1);
}
static void test(int... input) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input) + " -> " + Arrays.toString(evenOdd(input)));
}
```

*Output*

```
[] -> []
[1] -> [null, 1]
[2] -> [2]
[3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 6, 9, 9, 89, 10, 1] -> [6, 3, 2, 9, 0, 9, 0, 89, 6, 1, 10]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2] -> [2, 1, null, 1, null, 1, null, 1]
[2, 2, 2] -> [2, null, 2, null, 2]
[1, 1, 1] -> [null, 1, null, 1, null, 1]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what does 'if (( value & 1)==0)' do?

Comment: Also, can you please explain the logic behind calculating the size of the array? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @AanjaneyaShah Same as `if ((value % 2) == 0)`, it checks if the value is even, but using bit-wise AND operator instead of remainder operator.

Comment: @AanjaneyaShah If there are e.g. 3 odd numbers, then odd numbers would be at indexes 1, 3, and 5, so length would need to be *at least* 6 (`countOdd * 2`). If there are e.g. 5 even numbers, then even numbers would be at indexes 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8, so length would need to be *at least* 9 (`countEven * 2 - 1`). Two constraints on length, so we need the larger one, i.e. the `max`, to accommodate both *at least* requirements: `Math.max(countEven * 2 - 1, countOdd * 2)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a learner myself. This is how I would do it - if you want to store even & odd numbers in two different data structures, I would use Lists as following.

```
    //Ask for input
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no of elements");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    //Create a data structure
    List<Integer> evenArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    List<Integer> oddArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);

    //Ask for elements to insert, iterate n amount of times and set conditions
    System.out.println("Enter your elements");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int element = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

       /*
        if...
        else....
       */

    }
    //Print
    System.out.println("evenArr = " + evenArr);
    System.out.println("oddArr = " + oddArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//importing java package for scanner class

import java.util.*;
public class EvenOddsorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // taking size of the array from the user
        int size = scr.nextInt();

        int[] nums = new int[size]; // defining size of the array

        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
            nums[i] = scr.nextInt(); // taking array ele. from the user
        }
        
        //placing even elements at even index
        for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
            if(nums[i] % 2 == 0){
                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[i-1];
                nums[i-1] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        // placing odd elements at odd places
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if(nums[i] % 2 != 0){
                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[i-1];
                nums[i-1] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }
        // output of the program
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.